# How to make UIView fullscreen when user rotates its device from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, ytplayerview

I have a `UIView` that is actually `YTPlayerView` from [youtube-ios-sdk](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

I need to make it fullscreen when a device rotates left or right and return it to the non-fullscreen mode when the device rotates back to the portrait mode (like in the official YouTube application).

How can I achieve such behavior?

I don't see any `setFullScreenMode` functions in `YTPlayerView`'s interface.

Comment: Have you tried setting the view's frame to the UIScreen's frame size? Not sure if it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you tried to modify the view's frame when device was being rotated ?

This is what I do:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {

     } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {
         UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
         switch (orientation) {
             case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:

                 break;
             case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
             case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                 [self.testView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work -- `YTPlayerView` still has the same size (half of the screen)

Comment: It seems that another view prevents it (maybe because of the layout constraints) -- http://i.imgur.com/GRn2MCz.png. What can I do?

Comment: I did successfully on both devices and simulator. (YTPlayerView has layout constraints of course).

Did you implement supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate ?

Here's a simple video just made. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyjD4V-kGOQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

make sure your device can able to rotate display(Portrait orientation lock should be off).

Comment: I'm testing my application on simulator, so yes, it can rotate display

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, in xcode 9.2 and swift 4

```
var videoView: UIView!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) && !(UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat) {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        videoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
    }
}
```